# javascript child element css

Tags: javascript, css

I have two classes set in css
.dragbox and .removebutton

the .dragbox is a div and the .removebutton is an button within the div

I have multiple dynamically created .dragbox's on the page.

how do I make the .removebutton of only that current .dragbox visible with javascript?

currently when I hover over one .dragbox, all the .removebuttons become visible for all .dragbox's. I only want the current one to show up

heres the css

```
.dragbox
 {
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:25px;
  padding: 0.0em; 
  margin:25px;    
  }

 .removebutton
{
      background-image:url(img/delete.png); 
      background-repeat:
      no-repeat;visibility:hidden;
}
```

and heres the javascript

```
   $('.dragbox').hover(function() 
  { 
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #000');     
    $(this).css('background-image','url(img/move.png)');
    $(this).css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
    $(this).css('width', '15px');
    $(this).css('height', '15px');          
        $(".removebutton").css('visibility', 'visible'); 
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.dragbox').hover(function() 
{ 
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #000');     
    $(this).css('background-image','url(img/move.png)');
    $(this).css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
    $(this).css('width', '15px');
    $(this).css('height', '15px');          
    $(this).find(".removebutton").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Your original code will find every instance of `.removeButton` on the page. The above code will target the `.removeButton` that's part of the currently-hovered `.dragbox` div.

Comment: just have told me I had to wait 4 mins before i could accept it

Answer (score 2):

no need to repeat (this) also

```
 $('.dragbox').hover(function() 
      { 
        $(this).css({
       border :'1px solid #000'    ,
       background-image:'url(img/move.png)',
       background-repeat:'no-repeat',
       width: '15px',
       height: '15px'
    })
            $(this).find('.removebutton').css('display', 'block');or /*visibility:visible*/
       });
```